# Get Model by Id paginating the next 10 and the previous 10

Tags: php, laravel

given an id of a model I want to grab that model, the ten previous model entries and ten after the selected id, I also want to return them paginated.

So if I get id 11 I want to return ids: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10  <- 11 ->  12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

Comment: This will create issues for you, why don't you use any plugin?

Comment: @gabogabans could you please share code you use to get model?

Comment: @gabogabans  Have you tried using laravel's paginate functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Since model ids need not be sequential in the database, we can't take the risk of mathematical operations.

So we divide this into 2 sets.

- One is to get all rows less than model ID => order by ID in descending fashion => take only first 10.
- Second is to get all rows greater than or equal to model ID => order by ID in ascending fashion => take only first 10.

Now, we could just merge these results using `union()` and paginate them.

```
<?php

$model_id = 11;
$pagination_limit = 15;

$a = Model::where('id','<',$model_id)->orderBy('id','desc')->take(10);
$b = Model::where('id','>=',$model_id)->orderBy('id','asc')->take(10);
$c = $a->union($b)->orderBy('id')->paginate($pagination_limit );

dd($c);
```